# Laravel Eloquent получить все поля, которые NOT NULL

Tags: laravel, eloquent

У меня есть таблица с кучей характеристик. Например:
type: GPU, VRAM: 6, RAM_slot: NULL.

И мне нужно получить только 2 поля - type и VRAM, тк они не NULL.
Какой laravel запрос нужно для этого написать?

Comment: Набор полей скорее всего никак. Только после получения данных обрабатывать коллекцию (через ресурсы, как пример)...

Comment: Через коллекцию неинтересно. Мне нужно получить, например 50 записей по 30 полей каждая. штук 20 полей NULL. Зачем мне все поля?

Comment: Вы не сможете получить на разные строки разные поля. Реляционные БД так делать не умеют (Eloquent только строит запрос, магию она не сделает, поэтому тоже самое). Вы в любом случае будете это руками обрабатвать.

Comment: Жалко, спасибо. Если не затруднит, у меня в профиле есть еще 2 нерешенных вопроса по laravel)